# Cannot access Jenkins

Tags: apache2, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop machine using this guide:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu

I also needed to follow this guide:

http://aslamnajeebdeen.com/blog/how-to-fix-apache-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-using-127011-for-servername-error-on-ubuntu

From my other machine (mac laptop) I now try to access Jenkins through safari:

```
http://192.168.1.100/jenkins
```

where `192.168.1.100` is the ip address of my desktop machine but I get an Error 404. I have also tried:

```
http://jenkins
```

but nothing happens. What am I missing?

The Jenkins service is running on my desktop PC:

```
service jenkins status
...
Jenkins Continuous Integration Server is running with the pid 3713
```

And if I enter: `localhost:8080` in a browser on my desktop pc I get the jenkins web interface.

PROBLEM SOLVED:
I have followed this guide:

http://www.zzorn.net/2009/11/setting-up-hudson-on-port-80-on-debian.html

and it now works.

Comment: Have you verified that the Jenkins service has started? http://askubuntu.com/questions/80355/how-to-start-jenkins

Comment: Yes the service is running, see the edited post.

Comment: Did you follow the link at the end of the first post regarding "Setting up Hudson on port 80 on a Debian or Ubuntu machine" ? http://www.zzorn.net/2009/11/setting-up-hudson-on-port-80-on-debian.html

Comment: That solved the problem. From my laptop I can now access the jenkins webinterface using the address: '192.168.1.100:8080/jenkins'

Comment: I am also Facing the same issue Can you please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982670/jenkins-server-is-not-accessible-by-host-name-and-ip-address

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but not using Apache, rather only Jenkins on Ubuntu

I solved it by replacing `HTTP_HOST=127.0.0.1` with `HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0` on `/etc/default/jenkins`

Comment: I don't see the variable "HTTP_HOST" in `/etc/default/jenkins`

Comment: you can find the arguments for jenkins.war through this link: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins is set to listen on **port 8080** by default,
so you should point your browser to:

http://**localhost:8080**/
(or, in your case: http://*192.168.1.100:8080*/ )

**EDIT:**

If still not able to connect, you may wish to check your firewall settings.

Comment: exactly, you have to mention the port also (default is 8080)

Comment: @Michal, sorry you feel that way. Some did find it helpful. Please elaborate (or add your own answer).

Comment: I am sorry for being rude but writting that jenkins listens on port 8080 is like saying that when your computer breaks you should should restart it. I had a problem with firewall on the server.

Comment: @Michal, rude indeed, and not what the original question was about (this is not a troubleshooting guide, but an answer to a question).