# Jenkins server is not accessible by host name and IP address

Tags: macos, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on MAC Machine, I can access it using `localhost:8080` and also using `127.0.0.1:8080` from my MAC machine. Now if I try to access it using hostname or IP address, it is not connecting.

I tried below options:

1. `--httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST`
2. I referred to this post [Jenkins server is not accessible by host name (ip address)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570128/jenkins-server-is-not-accessible-by-host-name-ip-address). But I do not have any file `/Users/admin/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist` related to Jenkins.

Comment: when you are accessing it using the name, are you still adding :8080

Comment: @pnizzle yeah I am still adding port 8080, but I am not able to access